# Array not printing in full

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having issues printing the array in full. The code is set up to print a sequence of random numbers, and the number of random number sequences (1-12) is intended to come from user input. However, I can't get it to print more than the first random number. I managed to print the entire sequence before, but since this is an assignment and I have to use arrays, my first method no longer works.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randomNumber;
        int[] allNumbers = new int[12];
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 1; i <= allNumbers.length; i++) {
            allNumbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 999 + 1);
            System.out.print("How many random numbers? ");
            randomNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\n" + "Random numbers: ");
            System.out.print(allNumbers[i] + " ");
            {
                System.out.print("\n");
                System.out.print("\n" + "Even numbers: " + (allNumbers[i] % 2 == 0));
                System.out.print("\n" + "Odd numbers: ");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**New code:** Work in progress...

*Update2: Added limit to keyboard.nextint.

Encountered "string literal is not closed by double quote" error at the part where I try to print odds and evens.

*Update3: fixed error above (caused by typo).

New issue: the sorted numbers (odd/even) show up, but in the wrong format. They show up like this: 
Odd: 475
Odd: 123
even: 62
even: 680
even: 870
odd:457
etc. 
I want:
Even numbers: number number number number
Odd numbers: number number number number

Also looking to put a counter in there that counts the number of even/odd random numbers - is there a way of printing all that in one single print? Or do I first have to make a system.out.print followed by a system out print**f** for the counter?

**Updated code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Test7 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many random numbers?: ");
    int size = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\n");
    while (size>12 || size<1);

    int[] randNum = new int[size];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < randNum.length ; i++) 
         randNum[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 999 + 1);
    System.out.println("Random numbers: " + Arrays.toString(randNum).replace("]", "").replace(",", "").replace("[", "") + "\n");


    for(int i = 0 ; i < randNum.length ; i++) 
    if(randNum[i] % 2 == 0) {
     System.out.print("\r" + "Even numbers: ");
     System.out.print(randNum[i] + " ");
    } else {
     System.out.print("\r" + "Odd numbers: ");
     System.out.print(randNum[i] + " ");
    }


}}
```

Comment: that is because of the break; at the end of for loop however there are more semantics problems too

Answer (score 2):

Java arrays use zero based index.

```
for(int i = 0; i < allNumbers.length ; i++)
```

Therefore, the for loop should be as above. You should probably get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException otherwise.

Also, the `break` statement you have included in the for loop cause the loop not to run more than one time. You should always use a **break** statement with a condition (ex: within an if block)

Comment: I edited that in and the result is the same as before. Very strange.

Comment: No, just no numbers at all.

Comment: Correction: Just like before I get a single sequence, for exaple "645".

Answer (score 1):

Everything that Imesha said plus this statement :

```
{
 System.out.print("\n");
 System.out.print("\n" + "Even numbers: " + (allNumbers[i] % 2 == 0));
 System.out.print("\n" + "Odd numbers: ");
 break;
}

System.out.print("\n" + "Even numbers: " + (allNumbers[i] % 2 == 0));
//will print true or false, if you want to display the even and odd number, you should try something like this :

if(allNumbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
 System.out.println("Even numbers " + allNumbers[i]"); 
} else {
 System.out.println("Odd numbers " + allNumbers[i]");
}
```

Comment: I added your solution to the mix, but I can't get it to work properly. I posted the new, updated code if you care to have another look.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want the user to choose the number of random numbers, you will have to get this BEFORE you create the `allNumbers` array.

Second, like Imesha Sudasingha said, Java is zero based so the int i needs to be initialized to 0 to avoid an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Third, the brackets in the last part of the `for` loop does noting for you here. They can be removed without changing the result.

Furthermore you have a break at the end that basically stops the `for` loop after one iteration.

I would recommend you start somewhat from scratch and try to set up you program in this order:

1. Get the number of random numbers from the user.
2. Create the `allNumbers` array with the correct size.
3. Create a `for` loop that ONLY assigns random numbers to the `allNumbers` array.
4. Create a new `for` loop to print the results.

Answer (score 0):

Please read through the following code. Looking at the block you have started after this line `System.out.print(allNumbers[i] + " ");`, it appears that your concepts need a bit of clearing. The comments are there to help you understand better.

Since you didn't mention anything about the even/odd stuff, I inferred that you are trying to count the number of even and odd numbers, as you will find in the code. Let me know if this needs changing.

Please let me know if there are any questions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // how many random numbers 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter array size: ");

    int size = Integer.parseInt( keyboard.next() );

    int[] randNum = new int[size];

    // fill array with random numbers
    for(int i = 0 ; i < randNum.length ; i++) 
         randNum[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 999 + 1);

    // to print the array, put import java.util.Arrays; at the top
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randNum));

    keyboard.close();

    // go over elements looking for even/odd numbers
    // by going over the list 2 times, you can print the even in the
    // first iteration, odd in the second iteration

    // i am using auxiliary lists
    // ZERO-th WAY
    List<Integer> even = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < randNum.length ; i++) {
        // even number found
        if(randNum[i] % 2 == 0)
            even.add(randNum[i]);
        else
            odd.add(randNum[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Even: " + even);
    System.out.println("Odd: " + odd);  

    // FIRST WAY
    // go over elements looking for even/odd numbers
    // by going over the list 2 times, you can print the even in the
    // first iteration, odd in the second iteration
    System.out.print("Even: ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < randNum.length ; i++) {
        // even number found
        if(randNum[i] % 2 == 0)
            System.out.print(randNum[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Odd: ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < randNum.length ; i++) {
        // even number found
        if(randNum[i] % 2 == 1)
            System.out.print(randNum[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();


    // SECOND WAY
    int evenCount = 0, oddCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < randNum.length ; i++) {
        // even number found
        if(randNum[i] % 2 == 0)
            evenCount++;
        else
            oddCount++;
    }

    int[] evenNums = new int[evenCount];
    int[] oddNums = new int[oddCount];
    int evenNumsIndx = 0, oddNumsIndx = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < randNum.length ; i++) {
        // even number
        if(randNum[i] % 2 == 0) {
            evenNums[evenNumsIndx] = randNum[i];
            evenNumsIndx++;
        } else {
            oddNums[oddNumsIndx] = randNum[i];
            oddNumsIndx++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Even: " + Arrays.toString(evenNums));
    System.out.println("Odd: " + Arrays.toString(oddNums)); 
}
```

Sample output:

```
Enter array size: 12                                                                                                                                                         
[435, 420, 334, 248, 143, 340, 233, 940, 187, 315, 228, 132]                                                                                                                 
Even: [420, 334, 248, 340, 940, 228, 132]                                                                                                                                    
Odd: [435, 143, 233, 187, 315]
```

Comment: Yes! That seems to have corrected the issue I was having with the array not printing, however I need to print the odd/even numbers as "User1420482" described aswell as limit the number of number sequencees to no more than 12. I'll post the new code once I find out how to do that.

Comment: Please disregard the previous comment, I fixed everything exept the printing bit. I could still use some input on that issue.

Comment: @Varldsligist do you want all even numbers to be on one line and all odd numbers to be on another line?

Comment: @Ray Yes, exactly. I need them all on the same line because I'm adding a counter there that counts the number of random numbers generated. Something like this: Odd numbers (counter of generated odd numbers) and then the numbers themselves. Same for even numbers.

Comment: @Varldsligist You will need to add `import.java.util.List;` and `import.java.util.ArrayList;` at the top. I have also made a small edit to the size variable. Let me know how this goes.

Comment: @Ray I was actually working with ArrayList a few hours ago, but as it turns out the instructions for this assignment I'm doing specificly mentions that ArrayList can't be used, only array int[]. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Varldsligist haha take a look at the edit. you will find that you have 2 other options to choose from

Comment: @Ray Works like a charm! Big thanks! I'm gonna try and see if I can finish my own two different solutions I've been working with, just for the heck of it. I noticed by biggest mistake was trying to sort evens w/o the need to, like this: if ((randNum[i] & 1) != 0) {  I  I actually managed to print one successfully though:     System.out.print("Even numbers: ");
 for(int i = 0 ; i < randNum.length ; i++) 
  if(randNum[i] % 2 == 0) {
 System.out.print(randNum[i] + " ");

Comment: @Varldsligist Yep, precisely. I think it works best if you fight through it and figure out your mistakes yourself. I find I learn best, that way.

Comment: @Varldsligist It would be nice, if you could accept/upvote an answer if your issue is resolved. From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."